# Continuous data transmission between UI Thread and Worker thread running TCP Client

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, tcpclient, java-threads

I have an app (Android Studio) that continuously generates data (Joystick coordinates) based on the user touch, that I want to stream continuously to my NodeMCU using Socket programming. I implemented an Async Task to do this on a separate tread.

I pass the bytes of data to the AsyncTask via execute() method from the Main Activity. The doInBackground method opens the socket connection and transfers the data byte to the server and then closes the socket. With the next available user input this process gets repeated again. Now for obvious reasons, this is not very effective.

I haven't figured out a way to keep streaming the bytes from the Main Activity to a buffer on a separate thread which would in turn keep streaming the bytes to the NodeMCU without repeatedly closing the socket.

So here is the question. What would be the best solution for my problem? I have been reading about so many different things like Services, Threads, Loopers, RxJava and it seems I am getting no where.

Comment: have you checked out https://socket.io/ ?

Comment: Hello @SIMMORSAL: I tried out the Websockets solution. It works out perfectly. I think I will at some time in the future experiment with TCP & UDP protocols. But for now, I can concentrate on other parts of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Well my Preferences would be:

1. RxJava - because RxJava is supercool, solves a lot of problems like switching schedulers between UI and IO and is close to your domain. Think of your joystick device as an Observable constantly emitting events (thats exactly whats RyJava is good for).
2. Services - can be done efficient. It will come down to an Observer-Pattern provided by the Service. In Android its is common to expose some hardware through services.
3. Loopers - because they are a little more lightweight and easier to manage than Threads.
4. Threads - possible, but probably most work to do on your side and most likely to produce subtle bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I open a socket connection and keep it open if I am using Loopers or Threads? They do not have an onCreate() method.